# qpid_messaging ruby gem compilation fails (Apache Qpid messaging api)

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, rubygems, qpid

I have tried many things but, no luck, im on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. So Here it is the problem: 
http://pastebin.com/eYftQcaP

Comment: Please write out your problem and not just post a link to it

Comment: That is my problem, I have created that pastebin. that is the log output after gem install qpid_messaging command and it's so long, that's why I posted this way.

Comment: How about giving a description of what the problem is - once people have got the idea of what you're trying to achieve from your question then add code quotes for the section of the log (presumably) that is describing the error

Comment: The problem is that i can't install qpid_messaging rubygem, I have installed all the libs that needed, and finally started the compilation, but the compiling fails and there is the log. I thought that is obvious.
 "cqpid.cpp:2327:28: error: ‘TransactionUnknown’ in namespace ‘qpid::messaging’ does not name a type"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Edit your question to include all this information, not in the comments. Please write out a detailed question - good questions get more attention. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I solved the issue. I fetched the last stable cpp from `https://qpid.apache.org/components/cpp-broker/index.html`
and compiled and installed it with cmake, then gem installs succesfully